# What are the dates of the "real" press conferences given by President Biden?

Tags: united-states, media, joe-biden

I recently read [an article that claimed that President Biden as of the 7th of June 2021 had given only one "real" press conference](https://www.poynter.org/newsletters/2021/why-hasnt-president-joe-biden-given-more-than-one-real-press-conference/), where the reporter defines a "real press conference" as one in which the President stands at a podium for a considerable amount of time (at least 30 minutes?) and takes questions from randomly chosen reporters with follow up questions allowed.

This is at odds with [statistics from the American Presidency Project](https://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/statistics/data/presidential-news-conferences), which claims that Biden has held 6 solo press conferences and 3 joint press conferences.

If we define a "real press conference" according to the standard described by Tom Jones in the article linked above, how many has Biden held and what were the dates of those events?

Comment: I don't think this is a really bad question, no dv from me, but 1) The question has probably been answered by Tom Jones, presumably he has access to the same data that we do.  2) You get ranty about a press conference with BJ, but you were wrong about that being one counted by the APP.  3) It was very easy to find the events listed by the APP, and apply Tom's criteria to them and get the same answer as Tom. 4) The ranty bit in the middle makes this look like a push question "Biden doesn't face the press amiright?"

Comment: @JamesK Ok, sorry for the rant. I didn't realize there was a link to the dates from that page. In terms of answer to the question, it seems to be up in the air, because the 5 conferences after the June 7 date of Jone's article could potentially be considered real press conferences, so the answer could be 1 or it could be as many as 6 depending on how we evaluate the short conferences.

Comment: No problem, I've edited out the middle bit that is probably provoking most of the downvotes. And indeed, it depends "on how we evaluate the short conferences". (and the joint conferences).

Comment: Sad that folk still confuse commentary with articles, which shouldn't make any claims. Dude's basically using the No True Scotsman fallacy to knock down his own Strawman with artificial cut-offs about what's "real" or not.

Answer (score 4):

[Just a click away from the page you refer to in your question are the news conferences.](https://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/advanced-search?field-keywords=&field-keywords2=&field-keywords3=&from%5Bdate%5D=&to%5Bdate%5D=&person2=200320&category2%5B%5D=73&items_per_page=25) This site lists 9:

| When | Where | With whom | Length (including speech) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mar 25, 2021 | Washington DC | Solo | 1hr 2min |
| Apr 16, 2021 | Washington DC | Prime Minister Suga of Japan | 28 min |
| May 21, 2021 | Washington DC | President Moon Jae-in of South Korea | 34 min |
| Jun 13, 2021 | Cornwall (G7) | Solo | 30 min |
| Jun 14, 2021 | Brussels | Solo | 25 min |
| Jun 16, 2021 | Geneva | Solo | 33 min |
| Jul 15, 2021 | Washington DC | Chancellor Angela Merkel Germany | 34 min |
| Oct 31, 2021 | Rome | Solo | 26 min |
| Nov 02, 2021 | Glasgow | Solo | 29 min |

Judging the length is somewhat difficult, as there is often a speech and some banter between questions. It seems that these events are scheduled to last 30 minutes, and so tend to cluster around that time.

If you exclude introductory remarks and time given to the co-host of shared news conferences, there would be one press conference that fulfils your standards, that of Mar 25.

So it depends on how you count the half-hour press conferences that occurred after the 7th of June. These all were given during foreign visits. If you consider them to be "real" then Biden has given 6 press conferences.

Answer (score -4):

I guess since nobody is answering this question, I had to look into it myself. So, I watched several of the solo press conferences and while they are short, he is indeed taking questions from a podium and allowing follow-ups. The only real serious departure from historical practice is that he is only taking questions from a list of pre-approved reporters, who tend to be major reporters from the main news services (AP, Reuters, NYT, Washington Post, ABC, NBC). Also, the press conferences tend to be relatively short from 20-30 minutes.

So, I guess we might characterize them as press conferences "lite", they seem to meet the basic definition. So, the answer would seem to be 6 if we exclude the joint conferences.

Comment: This seems to be a restating of my answer.

Comment: How do you know he is taking questions only from pre-approved reporters?

Comment: Here is a report of Biden taking a question from Fox - November 2021. https://www.lgbtqnation.com/2021/11/joe-biden-unloads-fox-reporter-asking-garbage-question/